# linq query regarding many to many relation

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a many to many relation set up this way

```
public class Produto
{
    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public double Preco { get; set; }
    public double Altura {get ; set; }
    public double Largura {get ; set; }
    public double Profundidade {get ; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProdutoParte> ProdutoPartes { get; set; }
}

public class Parte
{
    public int ParteID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public double Preco { get; set; }
    public double Altura {get ; set; }
    public double Largura {get ; set; }
    public double Profundidade {get ; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProdutoParte> ProdutoPartes { get; set; }
}

public class ProdutoParte
{
    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }
    public Produto Produto { get; set; }

    public int ParteID { get; set; }
    public Parte Parte { get; set; }
}
```

This is my dbcontext

```
public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
public DbSet<Parte> Partes {get;set;}
public DbSet<ProdutoParte> ProdutoPartes { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProdutoParte>()
        .HasKey(pp => new { pp.ProdutoID, pp.ParteID });

    modelBuilder.Entity<ProdutoParte>()
        .HasOne(pp => pp.Produto)
        .WithMany(pr => pr.ProdutoPartes)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ProdutoID);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ProdutoParte>()
        .HasOne(pp => pp.Parte)
        .WithMany(pa => pa.ProdutoPartes)
        .HasForeignKey(pp => pp.ParteID);
}
```

One Produto(product) can be composed of many Parte (parts) and
one Parte (part) can be used to create many Produto(products).

I'm trying to write the following query:

```
produto/{id}/partes
```

That returns all the parts being used in the product with {id}

This is what I have now

```
public IActionResult GetPartes([FromRoute] int id)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    Produto produto = _context.Produtos.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProdutoID == id);

    if(produto == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var parts = _context.ProdutoPartes.Where(p => p.ProdutoID == id);

    return Ok(parts);
}
```

With the following test data (still using inmemorydatabse)

```
if (_context.Produtos.Count() == 0)
{
    _context.Produtos.Add(new Produto() {ProdutoID=1, Nome="product1" });
    _context.Partes.Add(new Parte() {ParteID=1, Nome="part1" });
    _context.Partes.Add(new Parte() {ParteID=2, Nome="part2" });
    _context.Partes.Add(new Parte() {ParteID=3, Nome="part3" });
    _context.ProdutoPartes.Add(new ProdutoParte() {ProdutoID=1, ParteID=1 });
    _context.ProdutoPartes.Add(new ProdutoParte() {ProdutoID=1, ParteID=2 });
    _context.ProdutoPartes.Add(new ProdutoParte() {ProdutoID=1, ParteID=3 });
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

However using postman over json all I get is this when calling
get api/produto/1/partes

```
[{"produtoID":1,"produto":{"produtoID":1,"nome":"product1","preco":0.0,"altura":0.0,"largura":0.0,"profundidade":0.0,"produtoPartes":[
```

When it should be a list of parts.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: It looks like you're only showing a truncation of the response. I'm guessing the request is actually producing more data than that, but Postman is only showing about 1 line's worth of data in the view you're using.

Comment: So you want just a list of parts?  If yes, I think you forgot your "select" in this case; try this:var parts = _context.ProdutoPartes.Where(p => p.ProdutoID == id).Select(p =>p.Parte).ToList();

Comment: @Reno thanks that did it!
But I have a question, if I run the get command over postman I still get some weird truncated data but if i just type it out on the browser localhost:5001/api/produto/1/partes I get all the info correctly. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

> When it should be a list of parts.

You aren't asking for a list of parts: you're asking for a list of `ProdutoPartes`. There are a few ways you can change your query to get what you want. One is:

```
var parts = _context.Partes
    .Where(p => p.ProdutoPartes.Any(pp => pp.ProdutoID == id))
    .ToList();
```

A few other suggestions:

1. Create a DTO class that represents just the data you *really* want to send back as part of your API. Use a `.Select()` statement to map from your Entities to this DTO. That way you don't get tons more information sent back than you really intended to.
2. It looks like ProdutoPartes is really just an intermediate mapping table. Remove that from your model, in favor of a [many-to-many mapping](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) between Produto and Parte. This way, your query becomes:

   ```
   var parts = _context.Partes
       .Where(p => p.Produtos.Any(pp => pp.ProdutoID == id))
       .ToList();
   ```

Comment: Thanks that also works.


1. I do have a DTO class for each of them, I'll edit those.
2. I was under the impression that was only the case for EF6 and EF Core is still unable to handle them that way, which I believe is what I'm using? (sorry still very new to all this)

Comment: ProdutoPartes cannot be removed because EF core needs it. It cannot handle many to many.

Comment: Ugh, you're right. I hadn't been keeping up on EF Core. Hopefully they'll [fix it](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1368) someday.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you all the parts for the specified `ProdutoID`.

```
List<Parte> parts = _context.ProdutoPartes.Where(x => x.ProdutoID == id)
                    .Select(x = x.Parte).ToList();
```

Is the data in your `Parte` class sufficient enough? Does it have all the info the client needs? If yes, then you are good.

If not, create a ParteDto:

```
public class ParteDto
{
    public Parte Parte { get; set; }

    // Put other properties here 
}
```

Modify your query:

```
List<ParteDto> parts = _context.ProdutoPartes.Where(x => x.ProdutoID == id)
                      .Select(x = new ParteDto { Parte = x.Parte  /* , other properties */ })
                      .ToList();
```

---

To be honest, if you are speaking to the DbContext directly from your controller, you do not even need a DTO and you can just return an anonymous type like below. Please note there is no type after the `new` keyword:

```
var parts = _context.ProdutoPartes.Where(x => x.ProdutoID == id)
            .Select(x = new { Parte = x.Parte  /* , other properties */ })
            .ToList();
```